# How to get info about stored procedure xp_instance_regread

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to retrieve from sql server the default path of SQL server is runing. I know something like should be work:

```
declare @dir nvarchar(4000) 
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',
N'SQLPath', 
@dir output
select @dir
```

Now my concerns is about what parameters names use to call this stored procedure from .NET

```
Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
 Using cmd As New SqlCommand("xp_instance_regread", sqlConn)
            Parameter= New SqlParameter("@THE_FIRST_PARAMETER"...
```

how i can get that? is there some stored procedure like sp_help but giving more information in detail about the sqlparameters?.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there is some information online, `xp_instance_regread` is undocumented and that means there's a risk in using it: a new service pack may change it completely.

It's not entirely clear what you mean by the "default path" (path to what?), but the SMO [`Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server_properties.aspx) and [`Information`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.information_properties%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) classes have properties for all the 'obvious' paths that you might need. In this case I think you're asking about the [`RootDirectory` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.rootdirectory.aspx).

Comment: okay you right, using the Server class and root property I got the path of sql server was installed, but what about get the path for reporting services? in some point at the beginning of this thread I thought that getting the sql server path installation i could get the report server path.... at the beginning of this, i didn't explain much. but what i need it's get the path of reporting services in order to copy there some assemblies to localize my reports.

Comment: That's a new question, so I suggest you ask it separately and with the tags for SSRS.

Comment: Of course, they can also change documented features without warning during an SP like they did when SQL Server 2000 sp4 came out.  They changed the privs on sp_MakeWebTask with notice previous to the SP.

Answer (score 3):

I will add the code that is working, just in case if anyone need it :)

```
Public Shared Function GetSqlPath(ByVal connectionstring As String) As String
    Dim rowCount = 0
    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("xp_instance_regread", sqlConn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim parameterRootKey As New SqlParameter With {.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                                           .ParameterName = "@rootkey",
                                                           .Size = 128,
                                                            .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, .Value = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
                                                          }

            Dim parameterKey As New SqlParameter With {.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                                       .ParameterName = "@key",
                                                       .Size = 128,
                                                          .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                        .Value = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLSERVER\Setup"
                                                        }

            Dim parameterValueName As New SqlParameter With {.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                                             .ParameterName = "@value_name",
                                                             .Size = 128,
                                                          .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, .Value = "SQLPath"
                                                        } '                                              
            Dim parameterValue As New SqlParameter With {.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                                         .ParameterName = "@value",
                                                         .Size = 128,
                                                        .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                                                        }
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterRootKey)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterKey)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterValueName)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterValue)
            sqlConn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Return CType(parameterValue.Value, String)
        End Using
    End Using
```